Can non-equilibrium plasma be used as an electrolyte in fuel cells?
Non-equlibrium plasma, or non-thermal plasma, or cold-plasma is a type of plasma where the elctrons are at way higher temperatures than the ions.
It is normally used to sterilize materials in the pharmaceutical and food industry, but it is electrically conductive and can be used as a catalyst for many things, including plasmatron fuel reformers.
But I can't find anything on the subject of using it as the electrolyte itself, since it is full of free ions and electrons, wouldn't it allow for the travel of ions between electrodes?

If you run serious current, wouldn't it become thermal plasma?

@Mithoron it would highly depend on the size of each individual cell, but yes, that would need to be taken into consideration


Plasma electron/ion temperature difference comes to thermodynamic equilibrium rapidly through particle collisions. In a liquid, as you seem to imply, there are too many particles in close proximity for a cold plasma to persist more than nanoseconds.

What possible advantage would ephemeral cold plasma have over a stable liquid or solid electrolyte?

It takes energy to create a plasma, soon dissipated as heat. How is that energy made up in a chemical fuel cell???


All that said, if you're still interested in using plasma to generate energy, look up magnetohydrodynamic generator.

There are videos about making cold plasma torches ("the thought emporion" channel is an example), and they use radiofrequency with minimal voltage and current and they use circulating gas to keep it from overheating.
You are focusing too much on how the plasma would be kept from heating everything when the question is about if it can work as a electrolyte.
